# What determines a "transient error" in AWS Athena query `FAILED` states?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_QueryExecutionStatus.html it states that

> Athena automatically retries your queries in cases of certain transient errors. As a result, you may see the query state transition from `RUNNING` or `FAILED` to `QUEUED`.

As such, when a query execution is in a `FAILED` state, how can one determine (ideally from the API) if it is a transient error (and thus will transition back to `RUNNING` or `QUEUED`) or not?

Comment: I doubt if you could get that level of log from Athena query status. Detailed log is masked from end user and need to contact AWS Customer support. Based on query ID, they'll assist you with details.